# How do I show chart axis titles using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm designing a macro that creates a chart using various ranges within a spreadsheet. My code for the chart itself is shown below but for some reason I can't get the left (primary) axis title to show. It work's fine for the right (secondary). The rest of the code works fine, it's all hanging on this one axis title that won't show up.

Any thoughts?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Union(range1, range2)
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    .SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleNone)
    .ChartArea.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .ChartArea.Font.Size = 10
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but could it be that this line is causing an issue?

```
With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Union(range1, range2)
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1 ' <------- This line seems unnecessary
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    .SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleNone)
    .ChartArea.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .ChartArea.Font.Size = 10
End With
```

**EDIT**
I may have found a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242825/1089416). It sounds like a bug, where the constant is being interpreted as `306`, but if you look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msochartelementtype), the constant is mapped to a value of `307`. So, just use `307` literal instead of `msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that ended up there. Sadly, removing it hasn't fixed the problem :(

Comment: @S7ewie, have you seen my edit? I think that should work for you.

Comment: Oh well done! Thank you! That's sorted it :)